# ValueError in python basemap?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

So I was just using python's basemap for the first time recently and I had a script that worked on a large dataset of about 30,000 points just yesterday. When I came back today, it stopped working and started giving me value errors when I added a new dataset. I don't know what could be causing it but I'm getting a value error?

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-16fa79cd74a5> in <module>()
     12     longitude = np.array(df[(df['FLOAT'] == x)]['LONGITUDE'])
     13     latitude = np.array(df[df['FLOAT'] == x]['LATITUDE'])
---> 14     m.plot(longitude,latitude, latlon=True)
     15 parallels = np.arange(-90.,90.,10.)
     16 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.pyc in with_transform(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs)
    534             if self.projection in _cylproj or self.projection in _pseudocyl:
    535                 if x.ndim == 1:
--> 536                     x = self.shiftdata(x)
    537                 elif x.ndim == 0:
    538                     if x > 180:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.pyc in shiftdata(self, lonsin, datain, lon_0)
   4775             thresh = 360.-londiff_sort[-2]
   4776             itemindex = len(lonsin)-np.where(londiff>=thresh)[0]
-> 4777             if itemindex:
   4778                 # check to see if cyclic (wraparound) point included
   4779                 # if so, remove it.

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Anyone have a clue? Maybe there's a data value in the array that doesn't work out right?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `np.where` in line 4776 is returning an array where it should be returning a single value. What are the shapes of your `longitude` and `latitude` arrays?

Comment: (2140L,) for both of them when I print the shape value.

Comment: That is, if you mean the longitude and latitude arrays I'm passing in. I don't know what basemap really does with them after that very well. It works when I switch back to an older csv file so I imagine there has to be something wrong with a data entry or two... I just don't know why it would cause problems with basemap as long as it's a valid pairing. The data range in the new file tends to run on the longitude from -179.829 to 179.796. The latitudes are pretty far from the maximum.

Comment: If that's the case, It seems there's not enough information to solve the problem without the problem data and code itself. Are the new and old csv files similar? If so, do a diff and see what values are causing the problems.

Comment: Well, it's 300,000+ data entries... I can only imagine it has something to do with trying to draw a line that extends over one of the map edges. It seems to work fine as long as the line I'm asking it to draw doesn't do that.

Comment: I was able to plot the data when it was cut up into non-contiguous sections. Each line being split into multiple small lines plotted on its own latitude/longitude range. That caused no problems.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by [basemap bug #214](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/214).

At the time of writing (2016-03-17), this bug is still open, so you will need to find a workaround:

- Sort the data prior to plotting.  Of course, that may not be desirable if you need to draw the actual line segments.
- Split the data up in subsections, such as you have done.